# How to calculate Euler angles of inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, rotations

Given three Euler angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, I can construct rotation matrix $R$ using proper Euler angles

$$
R\left( \alpha ,\beta ,\gamma \right)
= R_i\left( \alpha \right)
  R_j\left( \beta \right)
  R_k\left( \gamma \right),
\qquad \left\langle i, j, k \right\rangle \in \pi\left( x, y, z \right),
$$

where $\pi\left( x, y, z \right)$ is a set of all possible permutations of triplet $\left\langle x, y, z \right\rangle$.

Also Tait–Bryan angles can be used

$$
R\left( \alpha ,\beta ,\gamma \right)
= R_i\left( \alpha \right)
  R_j\left( \beta \right)
  R_i\left( \gamma \right),
\qquad i, j \in \left\{ x, y, z \right\}, i \neq j.
$$

Matrices are defined as folllows

$$
R_x\left( \alpha \right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos{\alpha} & - \sin{\alpha} \\
    0 & \sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
R_y\left( \beta \right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos{\beta} & 0 & \sin{\beta} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    - \sin{\beta} & 0 & \cos{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
R_z\left( \gamma \right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos{\gamma} & - \sin{\gamma} & 0 \\
    \sin{\gamma} & \cos{\gamma} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a formula that calculates Euler angles for inverse of matrix that was generated with known Euler angles?
I mean such function $f$ that
$$
R\left( f\left( \alpha, \beta, \gamma \right) \right)
= R^T\left( \alpha, \beta, \gamma \right)
$$

I can simply generate a matrix by $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ angles, transpose it and decompose, but is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What about Tait-Bryan ? Here the order is the same...

Comment: @Widawensen oh, thanks, I didn't notice. I should try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is  an inverse matrix for $R$  when $RA=I$.

Certainly composition of operations $$
  R_i\left( \alpha \right)
  R_j\left( \beta \right)
   R_k\left( \gamma \right) \ \ (R_k\left( -\gamma \right) R_j\left( -\beta \right)
R_i\left( -\alpha \right)) =I $$ however the order of rotations for $A$ is inverse here and I don't know whether this is acceptable for the solution of your problem.

For Tait -Bryan form you have listed however the order is the same.